# How can I check the end of animation using FLAnimatedImage

Tags: ios, xcode, animation, gif, animated-gif

How can I check the end of animation using FLAnimatedImage?
I have this code:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FLAnimatedImageView *animatedImageView;

NSURL *url1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"hand" withExtension:@"gif"];
    NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1];
    FLAnimatedImage *animatedImage1 = [FLAnimatedImage animatedImageWithGIFData:data1];
    self.animatedImageView.animatedImage = animatedImage1;
    self.animatedImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

And I want to detect when the animation gif end. How can I do this?

Comment: Close question. I implement the protocol and delegate and can check this.

Answer (score 1):

`FLAnimatedImageView` has a `loopCompletionBlock` as of 1.0.9, see [here](https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage/blob/master/FLAnimatedImage/FLAnimatedImageView.h#L27). Added in https://github.com/Flipboard/FLAnimatedImage/pull/60.